# Angular JS not filling up html after http request

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I started today with angular js, I did a few tutorials on codeschool.

I used this [tutorial](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/3/more-gems) and this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/)

The problem is: I successfully get my JSON back from the PHP server side (it's for phonegap)
but there is no way angularJS wants to show it in html.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="teamapp">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script> 
        // 
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TeamController as team">
    <p>   Click <a href="#" ng-click="loadEvents('team-1')">here</a> to load data.</p>


    <!-- <div style="display:block" id="team-list">
    </div> -->

    div style="display:block" id="event-list">
    <div ng-repeat="event in team.events">
        <p>Naam: {{event.name}}</p>
        <p>Url: {{event.eventUrl}}</p>
    </div>
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('teamapp',[]);

    //Teamcontroller 
    app.controller('TeamController', function($scope,$http){

        //Declare events as array
        $scope.events = [];

        //Load events from database
        $scope.loadEvents = function(teamUrl){
            var httpRequest = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: baseUrl + 'events/' + teamUrl + '/event',
            }).success(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.events = data;
            });
        };

    });

})();
```

My log shows perfectly good json data.

At somepoint when I used data like this:

```
$scope.events = 
    [
        { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 },
        { name: 'Bloodstone', price: 5.95 },
        { name: 'Zircon', price: 3.95 },
    ];
```

It worked, but It seemed I broke something that even that doesn't work anymore.

What is going wrong?

I'm searching trough tons of stack overflow posts and going to check angulars own tutorial also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose either to store data in:

1. a controller instance (controller as syntax), change your controller to:

   ```
   app.controller('TeamController', function($scope, $http) {
     var team = this; // the controller instance.

     //Declare events as array
     $scope.events = [];

     //Load events from database
     $scope.loadEvents = function(teamUrl){
       var httpRequest = $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: baseUrl + 'events/' + teamUrl + '/event',
       }).success(function(data, status){
           console.log(data);
           team.events = data; // store data in controller instance instead
       });
     };
   });
   ```
2. or store it directly into the `$scope`, change your template to:

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="event in events">
   ```

Comment: this seems to better fit in my context, ty

Answer (score 2):

Your `ng-repeat` is wrong. It should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events">
```

And you don't need the alias for your controller:

```
<body ng-controller="TeamController">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning value to $scope.event in html
u need to do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="eventdetail in team.event">
   <p>Naam: {{eventdetail.name}}</p>
   <p>Url: {{eventdetail.eventUrl}}</p>
</div>
```

hope this helps :)